# A model id come from another model, how can I set in route by ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My ember version:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
Ember             : 2.10.2
Ember Data        : 2.11.0
jQuery            : 2.2.4
Ember Simple Auth : 1.1.0
Model Fragments   : 2.3.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

And my route code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    console.log(1);
    return RSVP.hash({
      ...,
      user: this.store.findRecord('user', this.get('session.data.authenticated.id'))
    });
  },

  afterModel(model, transition) {
    return this.store.findRecord('company', model.user.get('companyId')).then(company => {
      console.log(2);
      this.set('company', company);
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    console.log(3);
    controller.set('user', model.user);
    controller.set('company', this.get('company'));
  }
});
```

Look at `console.log` code, I think the correct order should be 1->2->3. But sometimes it turns out to be 1->3->2.

But my `company id` must come from `user api`. So what is way I set it in route? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing just another solution, From [RSVP.hash api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_hash)

> Returns a promise that is fulfilled when all the given promises have been fulfilled, or rejected if any of them become rejected. The returned promise is fulfilled with a hash that has the same key names as the promises object argument. If any of the values in the object are not promises, they will simply be copied over to the fulfilled object.

So you can write your requirement like the below code,

```
model() {
        var promises = {
            user: this.store.findRecord('user', this.get('session.data.authenticated.id'))
        };
        return Ember.RSVP.hash(promises).then(hash => {
            //then method will be called once all given promises are fulfilled, or rejected if any of them become rejected.
            return this.store.findRecord('company', hash.user.get('companyId')).then(company => {
                hash.company = company; // Here i am setting company property inside model itself, so you dont need to set it in route and carry over to controller
                return hash;
            });
        })
    }
```

Note:I am curious to know if you can reproduce 1->3->2 behavior in ember-twiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the right way to do this is to put all your model fetching in your `model` hook:

```
model() {
  return RSVP.hash({
    ...,
    user: this.store.findRecord('user', this.get('session.data.authenticated.id'))
  }).then(hash => {
      hash.company = this.store.findRecord('company', hash.user.get('companyId'));
      return RSVP.hash(hash);
  })
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('user', model.user);
  controller.set('company', model.company);
}
```

Comment: Hi Lux ..by the way my answer is just a coincident :)